# Compare label.textValue.last with Array of Strings

Tags: arrays, swift, string, macos, character

I want to check if the last character of a string is ".", "," or ":".

Sounds simple, but I fail again with the Swift syntax. Here is what I try:

```
var waitChars = [".", ",", ":"]



if waitChars.contains(myLabel.stringValue.last){
   ...
 
}
```

I get an error because I cannot compare "String" (the array) with "Character" (stringValue.last).

So I tried:

```
var waitChars : Character = [".", ",", ":"]
```

Error because of mismatch String with Character.

Casting from String into Character with Character(".") fails as well...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
var waitChars:[Character] = [".", ",", ":"]
```